# How to place button anchor element to extreme right inside the parent

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

I am not able to set an **anchor** tag named **"Refer Me"** to the right of the parent element. Kindly note that I DO NOT want to hardcode any values for CSS. I want to use standard bootstrap classes.

**Working example:**

Refer Me Button is rendering fine.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bs-example" style="right-padding:140px;" data-example-id="panel-without-body-with-table">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading<a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Refer Me </a></div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Non working example:**

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bs-example" style="right-padding:140px;" data-example-id="panel-without-body-with-table">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading">Panel heading<a href="/Referral/Create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Refer Me </a></div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Issue**
Why the anchor tag is going out of parent when I use **"Pull-Right"**?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clearfix is an older overly elaborate way to work with floated elements.

You also need to add entries to your stylesheet for it.

But this is more modern and elegant method

```
.panel-heading {
    overflow:auto;
    }
```

This will force the browser to calculate the height to fit the floated elements.

This also works:

```
.panel-heading {
    overflow:hidden;
    }
```

Some older browsers may need `width:100%` or `width:auto` added to work but I haven't encountered that in a very long time.

Comment: Sir, do we have any class to put the button to center too?

Comment: pull-right, pull-left, what about if I want button in center

Comment: depends on what you would define as "center" given your example.... you might get away with "pull-left" then `.btn { margin-left:40%; }` (or thereabouts)

Answer (score 1):

You add clearfix  in `panel-heading`.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="bs-example" style="right-padding:140px;" data-example-id="panel-without-body-with-table">
  <div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading clearfix">Panel heading<a href="/Referral/Create" class="btn btn-primary pull-right">Refer Me </a></div>
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>#</th>
          <th>First Name</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">1</th>
          <td>Mark</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">2</th>
          <td>Jacob</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th scope="row">3</th>
          <td>Larry</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have tried alot to understand clearfix. But I never understood it. Can you kindly direct me to any link so that I can once and for all understand what it is and what it does. Or can you add some explanation.

Comment: Whenever you use pull-right or pull-left you have to clear its parent div otherwise it goes outside of div.

Comment: clearfix is NOT needed to solve the problem -- clearfix is the "old solution" -- use `overflow:auto` instead -- see my answer on this page

Comment: I accept `clearfix` is old solution but this solution is also very helpful.